# Problem reading pipe delimited file using CsvHelper

Tags: csvhelper

I am trying to read a pipe delimited file with no headers using the CsvHelper. I have set the delimiter = "|", set the HasHeaderRecord = false, set MissingFieldFound = null and IgnoreBlankLines = true. 
I noticed that my file contains an empty row at the end of the file. My file contains 3 columns. I have created an object to put these values in with string attribute for all 3. When I run my code the first variable contains all 3 columns and the other 2 variables are blank. Below is a sample of the file I am reading:

```
01001001|0.0|0.1200|
01001003|0.0|0.5000|
01008000|1.0|1.9200|
101384|9999.0|0.1000|
103073|9999.0|0.0730|
103074|9999.0|0.1600|
103491|9999.0|0.1460|
```

I provide this information in my summary. I can not read the file if I do not have the MissingFieldFound set. I get the following error:

"Field at index '1' does not exist. You can ignore missing fields by setting MissingFieldFound to null."

```
        using (var textReader = new StreamReader(@processFileName))
        {
            var reader = new CsvReader(textReader);
            reader.Configuration.Delimiter = "|";

            using (var record = new CsvReader(textReader))
            {
                record.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
                record.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
                record.Configuration.IgnoreBlankLines = true;
                var result3 = record.GetRecords<ItemFileInfo>().ToList();
            }
        }

  public class ItemFileInfo
  {
      public string ItemCode { get; set; }
      public string OnHand { get; set; }
      public string Weight { get; set; }
  }
```

I would like to be able to parse out the 3 fields properly to a list so I can make some updates on these values.

Thank you ahead of time for any assistance.

Comment: The file format is 0100100|0.0|0.1200|    Three records per line. Sorry about the cut and paste

Answer (score 4):

You need to map the columns to your class properties by index.

```cs
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@processFileName))
using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader))
{
    csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
    csv.Configuration.Delimiter = "|";
    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<ItemFileInfoClassMap>();
    var results = csv.GetRecords<ItemFileInfo>().ToList();
}

public class ItemFileInfo
{
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string OnHand { get; set; }
    public string Weight { get; set; }
}

public class ItemFileInfoClassMap : ClassMap<ItemFileInfo>
{
    public ItemFileInfoClassMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.ItemCode).Index(0);
        Map(m => m.OnHand).Index(1);
        Map(m => m.Weight).Index(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you David for responding. I tried by removing the trailing pipe, added an additional filed to my model with the trailing pipe. Neither one worked so I am still having the same issue.

Comment: That's what I get for answering without actually running it myself.  I updated my answer with a solution that should work for you.  It will also work if you have the trailing pipe on each line.

Comment: Thank you very much David. I have never made changes with out test lol. I implemented you changes and I am still receiving an error. The bright side is it is a different error:) The error is {"Field at index '1' does not exist. You can ignore missing fields by setting MissingFieldFound to null."} I checked my file and all fields are filled. I do have a blank line at the end so I add the IgnoreBlankLines = true; setting.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the blank line at the end or set `IgnoreBlankLines = true`?